# "Sorry, an error occurred while processing this request" instagram api python-instagram

Tags: api, instagram

I'm using python-instagram library to get access to instagram api. But when I run my app (flask rest api application), my auth method which use InstagramAPI and get_authorize_login_url method raise 500 error:

```
raise OAuth2AuthExchangeError("The server returned a non-200 response for URL %s %s %s" % (url, response['status'], content))
OAuth2AuthExchangeError: The server returned a non-200 response for URL https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?scope=basic&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsocialservice.test.5-soft.com%3A8515%2Finstagram%2Fauth&response_type=code&client_id=c5095d88cee14bac91a9341e6e82ff8f 500  Sorry, an error occurred while processing this request.
```

In my local machine it works without any problems but in the production server with different IP I've got this problem. 
I would be very appreciative if someone can help to solve me this problem

Thanks in advance,
Ron

Answer (score -1):

Please clarify:

> In my local machine it works without any problems but in the production server with different IP I've got this problem.

How can you be performing authorization on your local machine? Instagram's API requires a public url for `redirect_uri`.

---

Next, I haven't found any evidence to verify this, but I don't believe you can specify a custom port in your callback url (you've provided http://socialservice.test.5-soft.com:8515/instagram/auth).

---

Last, assuming it's your callback server that is the problem, that error usually occurs when you aren't returning the correct response back to Instagram. The server needs to echo out *only* the value of the `GET` parameter `code` as plaintext.

If I browse to here: http://socialservice.test.5-soft.com:8515/instagram/auth?code=test I get no response, which is likely the cause of your error.